# Advantages JavaScript+HTML5 over XAMP on a local computer

Tags: javascript

I have this idea of developing an application (or a companion application to another web based application) on a client. My initial idea was to run it on a XAMP stack on the client. Although this is perfectly feasible, I was thinking of a more compact approach using javascipt+html5 (with web storage / indexed db). I think that not running a web and database server would allow my application to become less resource-intensive. Any ideas please.

Comment: You confuse server-side technologies and client-side technologies. Javascript has no ability to communicate with SQLite.

Comment: Duri - you are incorrect.  HTML5 introduced first the WebStorage API, which is similar to SQLLite.  This is present in Chrome, Safari and Firefox 4.  This has been dropped from the W3C spec though, in favor of IndexDB which is a key/value pair.  There is minimal adoption of this though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you trying to accomplish with your app?  Keep in mind if someone clears the cache, they can delete all the data that was in the local storage.

As to "resource intensive", is this personal resources (like paying for a server)?  I rarely would advise anyone in making an app that is client side only with no server side backup, unless it's something you only need to use on one computer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are forgetting one thing, you still need a web server to serve the HTML and javascript to the client.

However could create a Adobe AIR app using javascript and sqlite. 
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/getting_started_air_js.html